# Python script doesn't run on Ubuntu

Tags: python, windows, ubuntu, pyqt5

I have coded a Python 3 script on my Windows PC and want to have it on my Ubuntu PC as well.  This script creates a PyQt5 Borderless window with Clickthrough enabled.  The window should be transparent aside from a label that contains a single image, labeled GreenRGB.png.  However, the PyQt5 Window doesn't show up.  Why, and how can I fix this, if you please?

## My Code

```py
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.acceptDrops()
        # set the title
        self.setWindowTitle("RGB Corners")

        # creating label
        self.label = QLabel(self)

        # loading image
        self.pixmap = QPixmap('greenRGB.png')

        # adding image to label
        self.label.setPixmap(self.pixmap)

        # Optional, resize label to image size
        self.label.resize(self.pixmap.width(), self.pixmap.height())
        self.label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents, True)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_NoChildEventsForParent, True)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window|Qt.X11BypassWindowManagerHint|Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint|Qt.FramelessWindowHint|QtCore.Qt.Tool)

        # show all the widgets
        self.show()
        self.showMaximized()


App = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Window()
windows = QtWidgets.QWidget()

trayIcon = QSystemTrayIcon(QIcon('test.png'), parent=App)
trayIcon.setToolTip('RGB Corners')
trayIcon.show()
trayMenu = QMenu()
exitAction = trayMenu.addAction('Exit')
exitAction.triggered.connect(App.quit)
trayIcon.setContextMenu(trayMenu)

sys.exit(App.exec())
```

PyQt5.12.8 is the version that I have installed.  After further inspection, the window is created, and apparently shown.  No bugs in PyCharm, and the program does not crash.  I suppose that Ubuntu could not be drawing these correctly.  The theme that I have installed has no troubles, as the default `Yaru` themes have the same issue.  After further inspection, the line that caused it not to show is this: `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)`.

Comment: What happens when you run this program on ubuntu?  Do you get an error message?  Do you get any output at all?

Comment: I get some GTK Errors, will update question.

Comment: That's why your question get closed. You don't provide all relevant information. Please post the full traceback you get or whatever error you get.

Comment: Thank you all for explaining.  It's much better than just being closed.

Comment: "This is unacceptable." Closures always have an explanation and a link that says *why* it was closed. In your case, it was probably the fact that you didn't provide enough details (which is the same as you're doing here). Also, if a question is closed, it doesn't mean that it is deleted or cannot be reopened, so: 1. if you don't agree with the closure, that's perfectly fine (mods and users are not always right, and there are thousands of posts every day, it's perfectly normal that some posts get closed by mistake), so ***explain*** why; 2. if more details have been requested, *provide them*.

Comment: 3. don't delete a question just to post it again as it is, as you'll get the same result; 4. if new details make the question indeed considered *valid*, users will vote for its reopening; 5. "The rules say" that you should also try to provide as much details as you can (read [ask]); 6. complaining and ranting won't improve the quality (and possible upvoting, thus visibility and possibility of answers) of your question; 7. the warnings posted above are just warnings, they are not critical and they don't cause application crash (I get them a lot on my machine, you can normally ignore them);

Comment: Whiile it is fine to add a *comment* to explain that you did your best to ask your question and will try to edit it if you receive constructive comments and that you do not want the question to simply be closed, it should not be in the question itself. That is the reasons why I have edited it out.

Comment: I apologize for my childish behaviour.  I just assumed that they were getting closed without review (literally seconds after posting).  I guess the community is just fast :)

Comment: It looks GTK warnings are caused by some extra theme for Ubuntu being installed (at least this is the cause from fast google search). I don't know if it can affect your PyQt application

Comment: I usually get those types of errors with custom themes.  I will see if they cease, and the application shows with the normal `Yaru` themes.

Comment: Hmm... The gtk warnings were probably irrelevant but at least they showed that you tried to give some info about the error messages. You should add quickly the true error message because the question now looks worse than it initially did.

Comment: BTW I often had problems in porting Python scripts from Windows to Unix because I did not pay enough attention to case in Windows. File names are case sensitive on Ubuntu, including Python import statements...

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 there's literally thousands of users that everyday review posts for closure, editing, reopening and other mod-related stuff. We don't close posts just because, almost all of the people that spend their time and energy to review posts are experienced in both programming *and* StackOverflow rules/usage, so 99% of the times if a post is closed it's for a (probably) good reason. But, as said, everybody can be wrong, just explain yourself, ask for clarifications. Also, please use `@user`. That said, that doesn't seem a full debug output, but it's also not very clear if the program ->

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 -> actually runs or crashes. If that's the case, you can try to put some print statements at various points in your script to see at which point it crashes, assuming that there's absolutely nothing else being printed on the output except for the. It will also be useful to know what version of PyQt you have installed.

Comment: PyQt5.12.8 is my PyQt Version

Comment: I'm sorry for your problems.  I have figured out the solution.  I am probably going to delete this question now. (it's just so embarrasing).  I will wait, however, just in case that is something I should not do.

Comment: At least you can share what the problem was and what was the solution....

Comment: I edited the question already, but I guess I should add an answer huh.

Comment: @Zany_Zachary1 please don't add "answers" by editing the question, as it makes it confusing (to anybody else reading it in the future it might not be clear if that is part of the solution or of the problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am so sorry for all of your troubles.  The bug was in the line `self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.Tool)`  I do not know why this broke it, but I commented it (will delete it) and it got fixed.  However, upon doing this, the label will not resize properly, and is always too small.  I guess that is for another question though.

Comment: `setWindowFlags()` sets ***all*** flags for the window (resetting any existing flag), so calling it more than once is pointless (as opposed to `setWindowFlag()`, without the final `s`), as only the last call will be effective. OTOH, there's also to consider that changing the window attributes *and* the flags (and the order in which it's done) might affect the result due to the complex way in which every platform deals with window properties. It's usually better to set the window flags *first* (at the very beginning of the init, which is why it's also an argument for the QWidget constructor).

Comment: Besides that, `showMaximized()` already sets the visibility, so calling `show()` before that is not only unnecessary but also wrong, as it will cause a further resizing of the window. Finally, please clarify what you mean by "the label [...] is always too small". Do you mean that it doesn't properly show the whole image?

Comment: Here is a video that explains everything.  Upon further inspection, the window size is in fact my screen's size.  Maybe the picture in the label is scaled up?  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vwh-MBKGxjkDXGEKRLDcv14PLZhj3ilZ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: That's probably due to the `X11BypassWindowManagerHint` flag: since the X11 window has no "hints" from the window manager, it doesn't know how to properly "maximize" itself (which is a bit unintuitive, but I also believe correct and expected behavior). Try removing `showMaximized()` and use instead `self.setGeometry(QApplication.primaryScreen().availableGeometry())` *after* `self.show()`. Also remove both `setAlignment()` and `resize()` for the label, and just use `self.label.adjustSize()`.

Comment: Unless you want to *center* the label in the middle, in that case leave `setAlignment` and just add it to a layout set for the top level window.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you so much.  Would you like to draft an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: I can't, as it's not in the scope of the question and would be off-topic. If you want, you can create a new dedicated question.

Comment: I will create a new question.  However, We will have to wait 5 days, as "I have exceeded the question count"

Comment: That's not a problem, maybe in the meantime you can improve your code or find a better or more proper way to do what you're doing. For instance, consider that the `setGeometry` above only takes into account a single screen setup, while you might want to think about more advanced configurations for which the positioning might change.